# Solving trigonometric equation involving summation

Tags: trigonometry

For $ 0 <\theta<\frac{\pi}{2}$ find the solution of

$$\sum\limits_{m=1}^{6}\csc\left(\theta+\frac{(m-1)\pi}{4}\right)\cdot\csc\left(\theta+\frac{m\pi}{4}\right)=4\sqrt{2}$$

I thought of solving this as the angles form an A.P , But the given sum does not
come under any standard type such as the sum of the sines or cosines of
the angles in an A.P.So I am unable to proceed further.

Comment: Is $m$ an integer?  How about writing $\csc=\frac{1}{\sin}$ and expanding the angle sums?  Just a thought.

Comment: I modified the sum again.

Comment: $\csc(\theta+\pi) = -\csc(\theta)$ so there is some cancellation...

Comment: @gedgar here it is pi/4 instead of pi.

Comment: @GEdgar:  so the $m=1$ term is the same as the $m=5$ term, and also for $2$ and $6$

Answer (score 2):

The left side of the equation can be rewritten as:
$$ \Delta = \sum_{1 3 5} \csc\left(\theta+\frac{m\pi}{4}\right) \cdot \left( \csc\left(\theta+\frac{(m-1)\pi}{4}\right) +  \csc\left(\theta+\frac{(m+1)\pi}{4}\right) \right) $$
Now using the formulas
$$ \sin u +\sin v = 2\sin\left(\frac {u + v} 2\right) \cdot \cos \left(\frac {u - v} 2\right)$$
and
$$ \sin u \sin v = \frac 1 2 \left(\cos (u - v) - \cos (u + v)\right)$$
we have
$$ \begin{aligned}\csc\left(\theta+\frac{(m-1)\pi}{4}\right) +  \csc\left(\theta+\frac{(m+1)\pi}{4}\right) &= \frac {\sin\left(\theta+\frac{(m-1)\pi}{4}\right) +  \sin\left(\theta+\frac{(m+1)\pi}{4}\right)} {\sin\left(\theta+\frac{(m-1)\pi}{4}\right) \cdot \sin\left(\theta+\frac{(m+1)\pi}{4}\right)}\\ &= \frac {4 \sin\left(\theta + \frac {m\pi} {4}\right) cos\left( \frac \pi 4\right)}{\cos\left(\frac \pi 2 \right) - \cos\left(2\theta + \frac {m\pi} {2} \right)}\end{aligned}$$
So $\Delta$ becomes
$$\Delta = -2\sqrt 2\sum_{1 3 5} \frac 1 {\cos\left(2\theta + \frac {m\pi} {2} \right)} = -2\sqrt 2 \left( -\frac 1 {\sin 2\theta} +\frac 1 {\sin 2\theta} -\frac 1 {\sin 2\theta}\right) = 2\sqrt 2 \frac 1 {\sin 2\theta}$$
I hope there are no typos... ;)

Comment: I don't understand what you are doing. $\sum_{135}$ where is that coming from

Comment: @Chandru: With $\sum_{1 3 5}$ I indicate the summation with index $m$ varying in the set $\{1 3 5\}$. "My" summand with $m=1$ equals the sum of the first two original summands and so on.